# CMake fails to link nested library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

im trying to build my first CMake project and it fails on `CXX executable NeuralNetLibrary`.

I get the `undefined reference to FFLayer::test()` error when building.
The full project is in here
https://github.com/JRazek/ConvolutionalNetLib.
Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're missing dependencies between the different library projects. For example, the `Net` library uses a function defined in `FFLayer` in `Net.cpp`, but the corresponding `target_link_libraries(Net PRIVATE FFLayer)` is missing.

This causes CMake to link against the static libraries in the wrong order, as it assumes that there are no order constraints.

If you fix that you'll find that you still get a missing symbol error for the destructor of `Layer`, which isn't implemented. You can add a .cpp file with the definition or just add  `= default;` to the existing declaration, in both cases it will build.

Comment: It compiles. Thanks. :)